# SOCKS 5 - Failure behaviour?

Tags: socks

I have read the [RFC1928](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1928.txt) several times and still couldn't understand what a compliant SOCKS 5 server is supposed to reply in case of failure. This doubt comes from the fact that the ATYP, BND.ADDR and BND.PORT fields from a SOCKS reply simply don't make sense if, for instance, a request with an invalid command is received. Must the server not send these fields or just send blanks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a failure reply, only the `VER` and `REP` fields are meaningful. The other fields may be present but are not used.  You don't even need to look at those bytes unless `REP` is zero.

Answer (score 2):

I just red putty source code, and found out that, when there is an error in reply (REP != 0) ATYP is IPv4 (1) BND.ADDR and BND.PORT are all NULL  bytes.

I guess this behavior helps developpers to parse requests ?